# Live formatting editText with markups/markdown

Tags: android, android-edittext, string-formatting

I have a slight issue. I wanna do something like we have here where we put in format markers **such as this** and *this* but I want it to appear in the edit text but not remove the marks for it. At the moment I'm achieving this with a preview button which displays an AlertDialog to show the previewed text.

I'm not sure which code to show as I have no idea how to do this at all. I also have no idea where to start on something like this. I've tried doing tons of research and it formats one word and then completely removes the markup/down for it.

Any help will be appreciated and I'm happy to supply any code whatsoever :)

Comment: You would need to make a parser. Alternatively, you could use an open source library, there are plenty, here's one: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-richedit/blob/master/README.markdown. If you would want to leave the marks you may have to implement your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this using a third-party library [RichEditor](https://github.com/wasabeef/richeditor-android) and took the ones that I needed. It works really well for what I needed so I would recommend it for people to use.

It uses a webview for the EditText and then converts the text into a WYSIWYG formatting.